# I want to send an email from a certain point in time

Tags: javascript

----- First post -----

I work to a stopwatch for a company that sells maintenance packs (in hours) to its customers. Each customer has a time defined in his pack. When an employee works for a customer, he starts the stopwatch and, when he has finished, he sends in a database the completed task (with the date of completion, a comment and the time spent in minutes). I am also asked to send an email automatically to the project manager when the time remaining in the pack reaches 1 hour.

I made the stopwatch in JavaScript and it is integrated in PHP code. I assigned a "flag" that allows to determine when to send the mail in question (contract time - stopwatch time).
However, the problem I encounter when using document.getElementById("flag").innerHTML is that the change in value of the flag only appears for 1 second. And since I want to send the mail in php via the mail() function, I would need to save this value when the flag is set to true and transmit it as a POST method to be able to send the mail later.

Here is the part of code of the stopwatch :

```
// Calcul de temps du chronomètre (en secondes)
function envoyerAudio(minutes,heures,secondes){
minAlarm = parseInt(minutes);
hrAlarm  = parseInt(heures);
secAlarm = parseInt(secondes);
flagAudio = true;
    if (hrAlarm!= 00) {
        minAlarm = minAlarm + (hrAlarm * 60);
    }
    if (minAlarm != 00){
        secAlarm = secAlarm + (minAlarm * 60);
    }
return secAlarm;
}

var resultat = ((tempsRestant * 60) - (envoyerAudio(min,hr,sec)));

// Gestion des alarmes 
if(resultat == 3600){
    audio.play();
    // Permet, lorsque flagAlert="true", d'envoyer un mail au chargé de projet
    document.getElementById("flagAlert").innerHTML = "true";
} else{
    document.getElementById("flagAlert").innerHTML = "false";   
}

if(resultat == 0){
    audio.play();   
}
if(resultat == -3000){
    audio.play();
    alert ("Arrêtez la tâche en cours !!");
}
```

And here is the php code :

```
<form name="chronoForm" action="http://localhost/chrono_test/envoiTaches.php" method="post">
        <textarea name="tempsChrono" id="chronometre" rows="1" cols="7">00:00:00</textarea><br><br>
        <input type="button" name="demarStop" class="btn" value="DEMARRER" id="btnStart"/>
        <input type="button" name="arreter" class="btn" value="ARRETER" id="btnStop"/>
        <div class="invi" id="divAffMasq">
            <p class="sousTitres">Si la tâche est terminée :</p>
            <textarea id="comment" name="commentaireEnregistre" rows="5" cols="33" 
                    placeholder="Commentaires..."></textarea><br>
            <input type="submit" value="ENVOYER" class="btn" id="envoi" name="envoiEnregistrement"/>
            <p class="sousTitres">Si la tâche est en cours et nécessite une sauvegarde :</p>
            <textarea id="commentSauv" name="commentaireSauvegarde" rows="5" cols="33" 
                    placeholder="Commentaires..."></textarea><br>
            <input type="submit" value="SAUVEGARDER" id="sauv" name="envoiSauvegarde"/>
        </div>
        <textarea class="infosCachees" name="user">' . $client . '</textarea>
        <textarea class="infosCachees" name="temps" id="tempsRestant">' . $tempsContrat . '</textarea>
        <textarea class="infosCachees" name="iduser">' . $id . '</textarea>
        <textarea class="infosCachees" name="affichage">' . $affichage . '</textarea>
        <textarea class="infosCachees" name="chargeProjet">' . $chargeProjet . '</textarea>
        <textarea  id="flagAlert"/>false</textarea>
        <input class="infosCachees" id="flagSave" value="false"/>
    </form>
```

Do you have any ideas on how I can achieve what I want?

-----  Second post after the Hendrick's answer -----

Thank you all for your prompt responses.

I tried with your code Hendrik but I'm a bit confused about what I need to add to make the upload happen automatically. I created a page notifyProjectManager.php with the mail() function inside. But it doesn't work.

From what I understand, I shouldn't need to create this page since in any case, the URL will contain keys so it will never go to the notifyProjectManager.php URL.

I'm having trouble with Ajax which I'm currently trying to fill by taking video courses but, due to a lack of time for this project, I'd like to finish the automatic emailing fairly quickly. While waiting for your help, I'll keep watching the courses and maybe I'll find the solution by myself 
Thank you in any case for your precious help. Good evening at all

Comment: This is not something you should do client-side. Do it server-side, via a cron.

Comment: When you set the flag to true, send an AJAX request to the server immediately to send the email. But as mentioned it might be more reliable server-side. E.g. make sure the server knows when the stopwatch started. Then have a Cron job running every minute which checks active stopwatches, and sends an email each time it's due (by getting the difference between start time and current time). Only issue is you also have to notify the server if the person stops working on the task temporarily before the time expires

Comment: What have you tried to check where the problem occurs? This looks pretty broad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should send a request to `notifyProjectManager.php` with in the `$_GET` variable the values you need. You can change `var paramsKeys` to add more keys.

```
// Calcul de temps du chronomètre (en secondes)
function envoyerAudio(minutes, heures, secondes) {
    minAlarm = parseInt(minutes);
    hrAlarm = parseInt(heures);
    secAlarm = parseInt(secondes);
    flagAudio = true;
    if (hrAlarm != 00) {
        minAlarm = minAlarm + (hrAlarm * 60);
    }
    if (minAlarm != 00) {
        secAlarm = secAlarm + (minAlarm * 60);
    }
    return secAlarm;
}

var resultat = ((tempsRestant * 60) - (envoyerAudio(min, hr, sec)));

// Gestion des alarmes 
if (resultat == 3600) {
    audio.play();
}

if (resultat < 3600) {

    if (!!window.notifyProjectManager) {
        var params = [];
        var paramsKeys = ['user', 'temps', 'iduser', 'affichage', 'chargeProjet'];
        for (var i in paramsKeys) {
            var key = paramsKeys[i];
            params.push(key + '=' + getByNameValue(key));
        }

        get('notifyProjectManager.php?' + params.join('&'), function () {
            window.notifyProjectManager = true;
        });

        // Permet, lorsque flagAlert="true", d'envoyer un mail au chargé de projet
        document.getElementById("flagAlert").innerHTML = "true";
    }
} else {
    document.getElementById("flagAlert").innerHTML = "false";
}

// get request (working in all browsers)
function get(url, callback) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
                callback(xhr.responseText);
            }
        }
    };
    xhr.open('GET', url);
    xhr.send(null);
}

function getByNameValue(name) {
    return encodeURIComponent(document.getElementsByName(name)[0].value);
}

if (resultat == 0) {
    audio.play();
}
if (resultat == -3000) {
    audio.play();
    alert("Arrêtez la tâche en cours !!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where your timeout/interval function is, so I can't be more specific... But essentially you could set a flag in that function at the moment the timer expires and then fire the email request in the same or next tick.

Now if you need the email to send. At X point in time, regardless of if the browser is open, you could use Cron on the server.